# for loop plotting in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, python-3.6

I am trying to plot sinc function in python in the same plot, which is basically a OFDM carrier signal, which will sums up in the second figure.

Can you tell me what is wrong. Here is the code snippet.

```sh
NoOfCarriers = 11 
interval = math.pi/50
f = np.arange((-5*math.pi),(5*math.pi),interval)  
fnoiseMax = 0.3
iMin = -(NoOfCarriers-1)//2
iMax =  (NoOfCarriers-1)//2
csum = np.zeros(len(f))
fList = [];cList = []

ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in range(iMin,iMax):
    print("i = ", i)
    fnoise = fnoiseMax*(np.random.uniform(-1,1))
    fshift = (i * (1//math.pi) * math.pi) + fnoise
    c = np.sinc(f - fshift)
    csum = csum + c[i]
    fList = [fList,fshift]
    cList = [cList,max(c)]
    ax.plot(f, c)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Here is what i got :
[image]

Here is what i expected:
[image: upper figure is the OFDM subcarriers and lower figure is the sum of the all figure]

- i don't know how to add stem function in python. basic math logic for the stem function `stem((i * (1/pi) * pi) + fnoise,1)`

updated plot after taking out plt.show from loop
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `plt.show` out of the loop, like that:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NoOfCarriers = 11
interval = math.pi/50
f = np.arange((-5*math.pi),(5*math.pi),interval)
fnoiseMax = 0.3
iMin = -(NoOfCarriers-1)//2
iMax =  (NoOfCarriers-1)//2
csum = np.zeros(len(f))
fList = [];cList = []

ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in range(iMin,iMax):
    print("i = ", i)
    fnoise = fnoiseMax*(np.random.uniform(-1,1))
    fshift = (i * (1//math.pi) * math.pi) + fnoise
    c = np.sinc(f - fshift)
    csum = csum + c[i]
    fList = [fList,fshift]
    cList = [cList,max(c)]
    ax.plot(f, c)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The problem is triggering `show` function (blocking) when not all plots are on the `ax`.

Comment: it is still not iterate value for c , all plots are overlapping each other. Does this means it is not taking different value of c ? please see the updated question.

Comment: @JayPatel no, they are not overlapping, their values are just quite close. You can use `np.random.uniform(-10,10)` instead of `np.random.uniform(-1,1)` to get something close to expected result. If you need more help, please provide some math explanation of your problem.

Comment: updated the logic and figure. basically each sinc function is OFDM subcarrier that carries the data.